# using Url.Content to display the file content with .net mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

In my .net mvc application, I need to dynamically insert contents from local files into a View  page. So that the contents from different files can be display with the same style. So I created a controller called StaticController and an action called General. Following is my code:

```
public class StaticController : Controller
{
    public virtual ViewResult General(string filePath)
    {
        return View((object)filePath);
    }
}
```

In my view I try to display the contents of the file with the filePath.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Tab.Master"          Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<string>" %>
```

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model)){ %>
         Sorry, page is under construction!
    <% return;} %>
    <%=Url.Content(Model)%> 

</asp:Content>
```

Then I tested the view with http://localhost:4789/Static/General?filePath="~/staticfiles/1.txt" and then I expect the content of 1.txt to be displayed. But all I got back is a nice "~/staticfiles/1.txt" on my screen.

Did I do something wrong? I used to display pictures this way. I guess with plain text, Url.Content doesn't work any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a comment or two, not sure why you've marked your General action as virtual and second, <%= expression %> will return the text of the expression. In your case the path you passed in so everything is working as you've written it.

Secondly, I think you'd be best off expanding your Action as below:

```
public virtual ViewResult General(string filePath)
{
    StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath(filePath));
    return View(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

You could move the file read into the View itself but the View is supposed to be dumb, just displaying what's given.

Comment: To answer your question. The "virtual" was automatically added by T4MVC. It needs to override the action method to perform its magics. :). 
I will do what you have suggested and see what the result will be.