# Showing a doc file as view in asp .net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement some thing like below.

- User upload Word Doc files like his resume to the site
- Clicking the "View resume" link should show the uploaded doc file in a new window.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892904/using-url-content-to-display-the-file-content-with-net-mvc/1892995#1892995) is helpful

Answer (score 0):

When uploading the Word doc, it should be converted to HTML, and then you can just fill ViewData with the document's body.